# change jquery slider value with code

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

```
              <form>
                <select data-role="slider" id="persons" >
                  <option value="one" accesskey=""    >one</option>
                  <option value="two"  > two</option>
                </select>
              </form>
```

How to change the value with jquery so that the slider moves, too? If this is not possible, them maybe just the value.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code you've tried.

Comment: I have already answered my own question. see below.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it:

```
 $('#persons').val("two");
$('#persons').slider('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which will slide as well as give you the value

```
         <form>
            <select data-role="slider" id="persons" >
              <option value="one">one</option>
              <option value="two"> two</option>
            </select>
          </form>
         <div><span id="test"></span></div>





       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('select').on('change',function(){
         var n=$('select').val(); 
         $('#test').text(n);
       });
    });
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xrTh7/)** 
I hope you wanted to achieve this. Please vote.